# Entropy rate of a dog looking for a bone

Tags: information-theory

My question is about Entropy rate of a dog looking for a bone. According to this problem, A dog walks on the integers, possibly reversing direction at each step with probability $p = 0.1$ . Let $X_{0} = 0.$  The first step is equally likely to be positive or negative. A typical walk might look like this:
\begin{equation}
 (X_{0},X_{1}, . . .) = (0,−1,−2,−3,−4,−3,−2,−1, 0, 1, . . .).
\end{equation}

Now I want to find $H(X_{1},X_{2}, . . . , X_{n}).$

Here in the solution it has been said that, since $H(X_{0})=0$ and $H(X_{1}|X_{0})=0$, so for $i>0$:

\begin{equation}
 H(X_{i}|X_{i-1},X_{i-2}) = H(.1,.9)
\end{equation}

Where does $H(.1,.9)$ come from?

And also for computing entropy rate of this browsing dog, the solution is like this:

\begin{equation}
 H(X_{0},X_{1}, . . .)/(n+1) = (1+(n-1)H(.1,.9))/(n+1)
\end{equation}
What is $(n+1)$ here?

Comment: Could you define $H$?

Comment: Definition of $H$ is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $X_{i-2}$ and $X_{i-1}$, we know what direction the dog is "currently" walking and where it is. The information gained by measuring $X_i$ is just "whether or not the dog changed direction", which is the result of a coin flip with probability $0.1$. So $H(X_i \mid X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}) = H(0.1, 0.9)$.

The $n+1$ comes from averaging the joint entropy over $n+1$ random variables $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Just to work it out: the joint entropy $H(X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ is, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule)

$$H(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^n H(X_i \mid X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{i-1})$$
$X_i$ is conditionally independent of $X_{i-3}, X_{i-4}, \dots,$ given $X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}$ because the only relevant things are (1) the past state, $X_{i-1}$, and (2) the direction of travel, determined by $X_{i-2}$.

$$H(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n) = H(X_0) + H(X_1 \mid X_0) + \displaystyle\sum_{i = 2}^n H(X_i \mid X_{i-1}, X_{i-2})$$

$H(X_0) = 0$ because it's fixed. $H(X_1 \mid X_0) = 1$ for an unbiased coin flip. $H(X_i \mid X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}) = H(0.1, 0.9)$.

$$H(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n) = 1 + (n-1)H(0.1, 0.9)$$
$$H(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n)/(n+1) = (1 + (n-1)H(0.1, 0.9))/(n+1)$$

Entropy rate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}H(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n)/(n+1) = H(0.1, 0.9)$

Comment: I can't seem to reconcile in the statement that conditional entropy $H(X_i | X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}) = H(0.1,0.9)$ with the definition of conditional entropy:

$H(X_i | X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}) = -\sum_{x_1, x_2, x_3} p(x_1,x_2,x_3)log(p(x_1|x_2,x_3))$ 
$= -\sum_{x_2, x_3} p(x_2,x_3) \sum_{x_1}p(x_1|x_2,x_3)log(p(x_1|x_2,x_3)) $

H(0.1,0.9) would be entropy of the conditional distribution, i.e. 
$\sum_{x_1}p(x_1|x_2,x_3)log(p(x_1|x_2,x_3))$
but how do we take into account the varying probabilities of $p(x_2,x_3)$?

Comment: I guess this is the special case of the conditional entropy $\sum_{x_1}p(x_1|x_2,x_3)log(p(x_1|x_2,x_3))$ is always the same for every pair $x_2, x_3$. So

$H(X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2})= \sum_{x_2, x_3} p(x_2,x_3) \sum_{x_1} -p(x_1|x_2,x_3)log(p(x_1|x_2,x_3))$
$H(X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2})= \sum_{x_2, x_3} p(x_2,x_3) H(0.1,0.9)$

and then due to marginalization:
$H(X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2})= H(0.1,0.9)\sum_{x_2, x_3} p(x_2,x_3) $
$H(X_i|X_{i-1},X_{i-2})= H(0.1,0.9)$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking this is there is a correspondence between such dog walks and sequences of the form:

$$(Bern(0.5), Bern(0.1), …, Bern(0.1))$$

for independent Bernoulli’s where there are n-1 Bern(0.1). The first variable encodes the direction of the first step, the next encodes whether the dog turns at a given step. Entropy is preserved under bijective mappings and the entropy of a sequence of independent variables is just the sum of the entropies of each variable, giving the same result as the above answer.